# Differences between 谁都, 哪儿都, 什么都?

Tags: difference

Differences between 谁都, 哪儿都, 什么都?

Am I making the following sentences right?

Everyone knows what he does on the weekend.
谁都知道他在周末做什么.

Everywhere he goes he’s trouble.
他去哪儿都是麻烦.

I don’t have anything.
我什么都没有.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentences are correct. `谁都` has something to do with people, and therefore `everyone`. `哪儿都` has something to do with locations, and therefore `everywhere`. `什么都` has something to do with things, and therefore `everything`.

Although you have your sentences correct, I have to say be careful with the affirmative and the negative versions. If you use `谁都+没`, then it should be`no one`. If you use `哪儿都+没`, then it should be `nowhere`. If you use `什么都+没`, then it should be `nothing` or `anything`.

Answer (score 2):

谁都: everyone;

哪儿都: everywhere;

什么都: anything;

Therefore, the three sentences are correct.

Comment: ps 都 means every so 谁都 means everyone, 哪儿都 means everywhere and 什么都 means anything.